# S3 not returning Accept-Ranges header

Tags: amazon-s3

For some reason I don't get Accept-Ranges in s3 response parameters. Example curl headers response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: ***
x-amz-request-id: *** 
Date: Thu, 24 Oct 2019 12:40:51 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 24 Oct 2019 10:35:55 GMT
ETag: "770dc36e888906bfc63641cbaf7775ce"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 1846218
Server: AmazonS3
```

Any ideas why? Also I have CORS setuped as that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
<AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
<MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
<ExposeHeader>Accept-Ranges</ExposeHeader>
<ExposeHeader>Content-Range</ExposeHeader>
<ExposeHeader>Content-Encoding</ExposeHeader>
<ExposeHeader>Content-Length</ExposeHeader>
<ExposeHeader>Access-Control-Expose-Headers</ExposeHeader>
<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the url of the request you are making but ..

AWS S3 does not send the HTTP header Accept-Ranges: bytes if you are using the default endpoint URL. Use the following format as the origin URL instead which serves the required Accept-Ranges header field: .s3.amazonaws.com

From [KeyCDN](https://www.keycdn.com/support/frequently-asked-questions)

Hope that helps

Comment: I'm using the following format url: http://bucket.name.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/images/test.mview?thumb=1

Comment: Yes that's the default end point url - you can see it says s3-website.

Comment: the object url in your case should be https://s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/<bucketname>/images/...

Comment: Correct with that one it works, the problem is that I can't use that one as cloudfront origin, as it doesn't serve index.html on errors...